# Synaptics touchpad settings reset after waking from suspend

Tags: suspend, touchpad, synaptics

I have my touchpad configured to register a 3 finger tap as middle-click using

```
synclient TapButton3=2
```

This works well, so I have set this command up to automatically run some seconds after login months ago already, using the Startup Applications GUI tool. This is how the relevant files look:

```
$ cat .config/autostart/touchpad-settings.sh.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=bash -c 'sleep 7 ; /usr/local/bin/touchpad-settings.sh'
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Touchpad settings
Comment=

$ cat /usr/local/bin/touchpad-settings.sh
#! /bin/bash
synclient TapButton3=2
```

So this worked fine all the time, but since a few days or maybe weeks ago, the configuration gets reset after suspending the laptop and waking it up again. 3 finger tapping then opens an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>-like window switcher instead of producing a middle-click and querying `synclient` for this settings value confirms that `TapButton3=0` again.

Any idea what might have caused this? How can I fix it or at least automatically reconfigure it after waking up from suspend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what causes it, but it can be solved quickly.

You can write a script and let it be executed every time after suspend. Here's how it works:

First, create a script that contains your touchpad settings. Mine looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#=============
# touchpad.sh
#=============
# This script sets up my touchpad settings at login/after suspend
# Executed from /lib/systemd/system-sleep

# wait for a few seconds for the desktop to be set up properly first
sleep 5;

# synclient needs a server to connect to
declare -x DISPLAY=":0.0"
declare -x XAUTHORITY="/home/<YOUR USERNAME>/.Xauthority"

# enable middle click
synclient TapButton2=3 
synclient TapButton3=2

# disable window switcher
synclient ClickFinger3=2

exit 0
```

Don't forget to insert **YOUR USERNAME** and to make the script **executable**: chmod a+x /path/to/script/touchpad.sh

Next, you create a script that will launch touchpad.sh after suspend. For ubuntu 16, you'll need to save it in the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory. This is what mine looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
  pre)
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` 
    # if no pre suspend action required
    exit 0
    ;;
  post)
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or 
    # `exit 0` if no post suspend action required
    /path/to/script/touchpad.sh
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```

You'll need root permissions to write into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`, and again don't forget to make the script executable with `sudo chmod a+x your_wakeup_script.sh`

Lastly, [credits where credits are due.](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2380045)

Comment: this approach doesn't seem to try to get to the crux of the matter